# Control ball movement by tilting device in Unity3D

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I'm using the following script to control a ball but it doesn't do exactly what I want.
Our 3D game will be played in landscape mode with the home button (or bottom) of the device in the right hand. Tilting (not turning) the device to the left should make the ball roll left, tilting to the right should make it roll right. Tilting the device down (top of device going down) should make the ball roll faster and tilting the device upward should slow it down.
I don't want the ball to indefinitely accelerate either.

The code below wants the device held straight as opposed to laying flat and it moves the ball by turning the device not by tiling it.

```
        void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Player movement in mobile devices
        // Building of force vector 
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(-Input.acceleration.x, 0.0f, -Input.acceleration.z);
        // Adding force to rigidbody
        var move = movement * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        rigidbdy.AddForce(move);         
    }
```

Comment: You have said what you want it to do, but you have not told us how it is acting incorrectly. Edit your question and include details about how your current implementation is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your tilting problem you likely just need to choose something other than `(-Input.acceleration.x, 0.0f, -Input.acceleration.z);`, [in the example in the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-acceleration.html) they do `(-Input.acceleration.y, 0.0f, Input.acceleration.x);` to do tilt controls.

For the max speed issue, just add a check for `rigidbdy.velocity.magnitude > maxSpeed` in your code and cap the value if it is maxed.

```
public float maxSpeed;
void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Player movement in mobile devices
    // Building of force vector 
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(-Input.acceleration.y, 0.0f, Input.acceleration.x);
    // Adding force to rigidbody
    var move = movement * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    rigidbdy.AddForce(move);   

    //Limits the max speed
    if(rigidbdy.velocity.magnitude > maxSpeed)
    {
        rigidbdy.velocity = rigidbdy.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
    }
}
```

That will cause the velocity to be capped to whatever value you have set for `maxSpeed` in the inspector.